# Dynamic Link Library for Java/Python to access in C/C++?

Tags: java, python, c++, c, dll

A quick question that may seem out of the ordinary. (in reverse)

Instead of calling native code from an interpreted language; is there a way to compile Java or Python code to a .dll/.so and call the code from C/C++?

I'm willing to accept even answers such as manually spawning the interpreter or JVM and force it to read the .class/.py files. (is this a good solution?)

Thank you.

Comment: Why specifically do you want to do this? There are a lot of options, but it's hard to know which one makes sense for you without knowing what you're trying to do.

Comment: There are some parts of my C++ network system that are not so performance critical, yet they require a lot of high level abstraction. So I've decided to write them separately in a faster (in terms of development) language.

Comment: Usually, the _only_ part of a network system that's performance critical is the core network loop. And Python libraries like `gevent`, `asyncio`, `twisted`, etc. are often faster than whatever you'd write yourself in C++ (as well as being cross-platform, less buggy, easier to use, etc.), so there's no reason to use C++ at all. Of course if you have other things you do outside the socket-multiplexing that are CPU-bound or need core-parallelism or talk to third-party C libs with no bindings, you can write _them_ in C++, but it's usually easy to organize those parts into extension modules.

Comment: I'm sorry for being slightly bold, but I don't think Python libraries nor any other language/library can provide the same speed or flexibility that IOCP offers from Winsock with C ;/

Comment: The core part of these libraries is written in highly-optimized, platform-specific C code, and then a simple API is exposed to Python to build your apps on top of it. If you've got a team of network coding experts building a single-platform streaming server, and optimizing scalability is the core goal of your project, then yes, you can obviously beat a library like that. If you're one guy who sort of knows how to write decent IOCP apps, then you're not going to.

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm a stubborn person and I'll stick to what I've read in cold text & saw with my own eyes in benchmarks. Can a python server hold 64,000 sockets and concurrently keep up with the throughput? I personally doubt it, but I will give those 3 libraries a look & test them myself. I simply don't give too much credit to interpreted languages - to me they're mere tools used for anything minor. Thanks for the input.

Comment: There's a benchmark with a Python gevent+cyrawr server doing over 70K sockets on linux. I don't know if anyone's done it with Windows or not, but you could search rather than just assuming it's not possible. And again, the point is that the networking core (in that case, `libev`), the part that actually matters, is written in C, not Python.

Comment: Also, remember that if you're trying to run Python code, you not only have to get the event loop right, you _also_ have to get the dispatching-to-python part right. You really think you're going to do better at _both_ parts (and again, consider robustness, flexibility, and usability, not just performance) than a library that's in heavy development?

Comment: Nope, but it doesn't stop me from trying. Also, I won't be using python for more than some simple pipes, it's rendering/graphics API (whatever it's called - will find out soon) and a binding to a gui. Getting the event loop right is simple - implementing it to suit my server design and protocol is where the challenge lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[gcj](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) can compile most Java source to native code (linked with a `libgcj` shared library) instead of to JVM bytecode.

There are a number of Python projects that are similar, like [shedskin](http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/), but none as mature or active.

[`Cython`](http://cython.org) is similar, but not quite the same—it compiles modules written in a Python-like language into native C extension modules for CPython. But if you put that together with [embedding Python in a C app](http://docs.python.org/3.3/extending/embedding.html#very-high-level-embedding), it gives you most of what you want. But you are still running a Python interpreter loop to tie all those compiled-to-C functions together.

You can also do the same thing with Java—embed the JVM into your app, use `gcj` to compile any parts you want to native code, while compiling other parts to bytecode, and using [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to communicate between them.

And of course you can use [Jython](http://www.jython.org) to embed your Python code into the JVM, which you can embed into your C program, and because you can use JNI directly from Jython any pair of the three languages can effectively talk to each other without going through the third.

The idea of spawning a JVM or a CPython interpreter as a subprocess, which I think you were suggesting in your question, also works just fine. However, the only interface you will have to it in that case will be the child process's stdin/stdout/stderr (or any pipes or sockets you create manually), which isn't as flexible as being able to call methods directly on objects, etc. (Then again, sometimes that extra indirection can be a good thing, forcing you to define a cleanly-separated API between your components.)

Comment: Will definitely take your answer into account and look at those links - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a Python interpreter in your C/C++ program.

http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html

With Java your probably want the Java Native Interface (which works in both directions).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into Lua, while not as widely used as a lot of other scripting languages, it was meant to be embedded easily into executables. It's relatively small and fast. Just another option. If you want to call other languages from your c/c++ look into SWIG.